# Android: is it possible to apply direction of alpha animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

In my android application, I want to set alpha effect on an imageView. I want to animate the imageView from alpha value 0.0 to 1.0 so that the imageView gradually become visible.

my animation xml is given here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" android:fillEnabled="true"  android:fillAfter="true">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"  android:duration="1200"/> 
</set>
```

Now I want to set direction for the visibility. I want the imageView will start to be visualized from left side and towards right. How can I set direction for this?...using "pivot" or something else!

Comment: You must make a customAnimation, by overriding the onAppplyTransformation method from Animation.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this via a scale animation

Comment: Scale animation stretches a view from 0 to 1.
I dont want the view to be compressed during the animation.
is it possible to scale a view without compression or stretching?